# "was ist der Unterschied" vs. "was ist die Differenz"

Tags: difference

I noticed "Differenz" is the equivalent of the English word "difference", since I used "Unterschied" till now.

Are the two completely interchangeable?

Comment: Unterschied/Unterscheidung is more like distinction: "Seine außergewöhnliche Stimme unterscheidet ihn von den anderen Teilnehmern (His extraordinary voice made the distinction between him and the others participants)" or "Die neue Gesetzgebung unterscheidet nicht zwischen Kindern und Erwachsenen. (The new law makes no distinction between adults and children)"

Comment: @Em1: Was ist mit "Die Stimme differnzierte ihn?" Und mit. "Die Gesetzgebung differenziert nicht zwischen Beamtenbeleidigung und Arbeiterbeleidigung"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Differenz" is strictly a mathematical term. It is the quantitative difference between two numbers:

> Was ist die Differenz von 9 und 3?
>
> Antwort: 6

whereas "Unterschied" typically means a *qualitative* difference, which can have more than one answer:

> Was ist der Unterschied zwischen 9 und 3?
>
> Antwort 1: 9 ist größer als 3.
>
> Antwort 2: 3 ist eine Primzahl, 9 nicht.
>
> Antwort 3: 9 ist eine Quadratzahl, 3 nicht.

Also note that "Differenzen", in plural, almost always means "conflicting views (of 2 or more persons) on a certain matter". I would not use it in singular in this meaning and don't think I've ever seen it used in singular this way.

Example:

> Nach unserem Gespräch konnten wir unsere Differenzen beilegen.
>
> After our talk, we could settle our differences.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "conflicting views" which is an important meaning of the German "Differenz(en)"

Comment: Ich denke, wenn wir in genau einer Frage unterschiedlicher Meinung sind haben wir da eine Differenz. Außerdem kann man natürlich die Differenzen zwischen Einnahmen und Ausgaben bilden, zwischen Preisen bei Hinz und Kunz, in den Temperaturaufzeichnungen des 19. Jhr. und heute und, und, und.

Answer (score 9):

**"Unterschied"** generally ***compares*** two subjects with each other, whereas 

**"Differenz"** asks for a ***quantity*** to describe the distinction.

For this reason both expressions are *not interexchangeable*.

Here is an example where such an attempt would fail:

> - Was ist der Unterschied zwischen einem Apfel und einer Karotte? - a meaningful question
> - Was ist die Differenz zwischen einem Apfel und einer Karrotte? - ???

The latter question asks for a quantity that separates an Apple and a carrot - which does not make sense to ask when taking about objects such as food.

When using the term "Differenz", the two **compared objects need to be of the same kind** (or set - in mathematics).

For example, you can extend the second question and make it meaningful by referring to an attribute that they have in common:

> Was ist Differenz *der Gewichte* von dem Apfel und der Karotte?

The compared objects are "Gewicht des Apfels" and "Gewicht der Karotte".

Comment: Nice to see you here! Shouldn't your first question have "zwischen" as well?

Answer (score 5):

No, they're not interchangeable. If you say *Differenz*, then I think of something like `2-1`, for which the English *difference* is also appropriate. But for

> What's the difference between *Unterschied* and *Differenz?*

you should use "Was ist der Unterschied".

Comment: Zwischen Kanzler und Präsidentin bestehen keine Differenzen.